# A change in internal energy in the Joule-Thomson effect

Tags: thermodynamics

I have trouble understanding [Joule-Thomson effect](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Joule%E2%80%93Thomson_effect), may be i am missing some basic concepts of thermodynamics.
We have two chambers. When we compress ideal gas to low volume by external work (adiabatic process), We increase its internal energy 
and hence temperature. And then we release this compressed gas through plug to vacuum. 
Here is the problem arise. Final Internal energy is same as before. But how? Compressed gas is released to vacuum and hence no work is done by the gas.

Answer (score 1):

I think you answered your question. If no work is done and no heat transfer occurs then by first law there is no change in internal energy

> So my question is does the internal energy of the gas before work is
>   done on it (compressing it) as same as after it is expended to vacuum?

No. The internal energy before the compression work is done on it is less than the internal energy of the gas after it expanded into the vacuum.

The internal energy of the gas increased when it was compressed. When it expanded into the vacuum, its internal energy does not change because the gas does no work when it expands into the vacuum. It keeps the increase given to it by the compression. In order for the gas to do work when it expands it must expand against some resistance (force).  The vacuum offers no resistance to the expansion.

Hope this helps

Comment: We do work in first place so ideal gas internal energy is increased but in second place, gas in released to vacuum hence so no work in done in second place.

Comment: Whole process is adiabatic

Comment: And...? In the first place an external (to the system) force does work adding energy to the gas. In the free expansion of the gas it is isolated from the surroundings. Expansion in a  vacuum involves no work by the gas. First law $\Delta U=Q-W$. $W=0$, $Q=0$ (adiabatic). Therefore $\Delta U =0$. What about this don’t you understand?

Comment: So my question is does the internal energy of the gas before  work is done on it (compressing it) as same as after it is expended to vacuum?

Comment: I have trouble understanding joule Thomson effect. Can you explain it to me?

Comment: @MuhammadNuman Read about it here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Joule%E2%80%93Thomson_effect After reading tell me specifically what you do not understand.

Comment: @MuhammadNuman Sorry, I didn't see your comment prior to your comment about the Joule Thompson effect. I have revised my answer to respond to it. You don't need to understand the Joule Thompson effect to understand why there is no change in internal energy in your example. I covered that. You need to understand it when a real gas vs and ideal gas is involved. For an ideal gas, no change in internal energy means no change in temperature. For a real gas, there can be a decrease in temperature. That's the Joule Thompson effect. But there is no internal energy change for a real or ideal gas.

Comment: @BobD In Joule-Thompson effect the enthalpy is conserved. Is internal energy also conserved?

Comment: @adosar There is no change in internal energy.

Comment: @BobD How can I prove it?

Comment: @adosar From the first law, $\Delta U=Q-W$. For the free expansion in a rigid thermally insulated chamber, the system is isolated from the surroundings. There is no heat transfer and no work done between the system and surroundings, so $\Delta U=0$.

Comment: @BobD In the Joule-Thomson the expansion is isenthalpic and not free. The system goes from a higher pressure ($P_1$) to a lower pressure ($P_2)$. $\Delta H=0 \Rightarrow H_1 + P_1\cdot \Delta V_1 = H_2 + P_2\cdot \Delta V_2$. You must prove that $$w_1=w_2$$ so the change in internal energy is zero.

Comment: @adosar The problem here is the OP is not describing the Joule Thompson Effect.  He is describing a free expansion into a vacuum. No work is done in this case. The Joule Thompson Effect  involves expansion from a higher pressure region to a lower pressure region without significant  change in kinetic energy.  Work is done. My answer in in response to the question as posed, namely, expansion of an ideal gas into a vacuum.

Comment: @BobD Ok, anyways thanks for the answer. I was asking because I am trying to understand Joule-Thomson effect in microscale.